# Block Thread execution until completed in test Python Django

Tags: python, django, multithreading, mocking, python-unittest

I have a Django app that needs to make some 3d service call to compute embedding. This call takes time and blocking execution and I want to make it async. For this I am using Thread.

```
class MyView():
    def create_answer_embedding(answer):
        embedding = long_computing_call(answer)
        db.write(embedding) <- pseudo code, the idea is that after creating the embedding, we create an AnswerEmbedding obj. in the db
    
    def post(request, *args, **kwargs):
        answer = request.data.get("answer")
        Thread(target=self.create_answer_embedding, args=(answer, )).start()
        return Response()
```

So the thread starts calculating embedding and the view returns a response. Once calculating is finished, a new AnswerEmbedding object is created in the DB.

Now I need to test it works properly. So if I just run a test that makes an api call:

```
response = client.post("/my-view")
answer_embedding = AnswerEmbedding.objects.get(answer__id=response.json()['id'])
```

This test fails because it checks `AnswerEmbedding.objects.get` before it is actually created in the Thread.

So, I need to somehow either make this Thread running sync or find a way to properly mock it. I could just mock the Thread but with this the test will not check if the embedding is created or not.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering, What's the point of using thread?

if you still want to block it, I think you could use `join()`

```
class MyView():
    def create_answer_embedding(answer):
        embedding = long_computing_call(answer)
        db.write(embedding)
    
    def post(request, *args, **kwargs):
        answer = request.data.get("answer")
        th = Thread(target=self.create_answer_embedding, args=(answer, ))
        th.start()
        th.join()
        return Response()
```

or if your problem is waiting the `embedding` to be created you can use state checker

```
class MyView():
    is_embedding_created = False

    def create_answer_embedding(answer):
        embedding = long_computing_call(answer)
        MyView.is_embedding_created = True
        db.write(embedding)
        MyView.is_embedding_created = False
    
    def post(request, *args, **kwargs):
        answer = request.data.get("answer")
        Thread(target=self.create_answer_embedding, args=(answer, )).start()
        while not MyView.is_embedding_created:
            time.sleep(0.1) # use a delay while waiting to reduce resource consumption
        return Response()
```

Comment: create_answer_embedding uses long_computing_call that can be a long computation that's why we need this to be async. The response does not need to wait for the embedding to be created. In this example you make it sync. My implementation works fine but is hard to test as there is no way to make this function call sync (for the test only)